# Kotlin - Issue in converting Kotlin method to java for LayerDrawable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layerdrawable

Below is the converted java function from Kotlin code funcion.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void setWhiteNavigationBar(@NonNull Dialog dialog) {
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        GradientDrawable dimDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        GradientDrawable navigationBarDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        navigationBarDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        navigationBarDrawable.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        val layers = arrayOf<Drawable>(dimDrawable, navigationBarDrawable)

        LayerDrawable windowBackground = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        windowBackground.setLayerInsetTop(1, metrics.heightPixels);

        window.setBackgroundDrawable(windowBackground);
    }
}
```

I have trouble for the below line inside that fucntion.
I am confused how can I write below kotlin line in Java :

```
val layers = arrayOf<Drawable>(dimDrawable, navigationBarDrawable)
```

So, Anyone please guide how can we write this line in java ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out `arrayOf()` in kotlin is a method to create an array of specific type. In your case `Drawable`. In Java, you can create this by:

```
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[] {dimDrawable, navigationBarDrawable}
```

You can omit `new Drawable[]` and write:

```
Drawable[] drawables = {dimDrawable, navigationBarDrawable}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just convert kotlin code to java we do have option in android studio.

```
you can go to Tools > Kotlin > Show kotlin bytecode
```

And it will show you entire java code for that class.

And here is your solution :

```
  public void setWhiteNavigationBar(@NonNull Dialog dialog) {
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        GradientDrawable dimDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        GradientDrawable navigationBarDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
        navigationBarDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        navigationBarDrawable.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        GradientDrawable [] layers =new GradientDrawable[] 
   {dimDrawable,navigationBarDrawable};

        LayerDrawable windowBackground = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        windowBackground.setLayerInsetTop(1, metrics.heightPixels);

        window.setBackgroundDrawable(windowBackground);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, It's disabled and gray in my android studio.

Comment: Drawable[] layers = {dimDrawable, navigationBarDrawable};   worked for me.